# Why are there diodes going to D+ on this alternator/generator?

Tags: voltage-regulator, diodes, generator

[image: Schematic]

Above is a schematic of an alternator/generator. I understand the rectification going to B+, but I don't understand why there are 3 diodes going to D+.

The way I understand the setup, D+ measures the voltage at the battery, and the delta between that and the preset voltage in the regulator drives the field to increase/decrease the output of the generator. I know why you need the diodes to charge the batteries, but why would you put the rectified current on the D+ sensor line? Seems like that would defeat the purpose of the sensor.

Maybe I'm completely misreading the diagram, if so, please point out my error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a misconception about what the regulator of a car alternator does. It doesn't regulate the voltage of the battery, and so, it doesn't measure the voltage of the battery either.

The regulator is there so the voltage **delivered** to the battery to charge it is independent from the speed of the drive shaft.

The regulator does this (simply said) by controlling the field winding of the alternator. That's the winding on the rotor, in your schematic that one on the right. This field winding needs some power, and it has to be independent from the battery, so the speed the alternator runs at can be measured.

That's why these three leftmost diodes are there. They provide an additional DC output which is not filtered to "pure DC" by the battery. Instead, it still has an AC part with a frequency dependent on the drive speed.

Comment: So you are saying I should not be connecting D+ to the battery at all?

Comment: Right. Battery plus goes to B+. The purpose of the D+ contact is to connect the battery indicator lamp inside the instrument panel (against B+). When the alternator is stopped or broken, this lamp supplies current for the alternator field winding, and lights up to indicate the error condition.

Comment: Why is that smoothing capacitor drawn with a dashed line?

Comment: I much more think it's an EMC filtering cap.

Comment: +1 fascinating. But how does the whole system regulate the battery charging current? Does it limit it? Is there any feedback?

Comment: It doesn't regulate the charging current. Lead acid batteries are charged with a constant voltage, not a constant current.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot this constant voltage. Do I understand this correctly, that higher D+ is (due to higher rpm), less current is supplied into DF by the "regulator"?

Comment: In short words, yes.

Comment: So the lightbulb that is connected to D+ has the other end of the bulb connected to the Battery Positive, and when something fails, current flows from the Battery, thru the bulb, a diode (to keep the current flow unidirectional) and into the field winding.  The current flow from the Battery (because it is higher that D+) cause the lamp to glow.  Meaning this can't be and LED indicator, but actually needs to be a incandescent bulb. The brightness of the bulb will indicate the level of failure.  Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, incandescent bulb only, about 0.5W. When there's a failure, the bulb may glow dimly (regulator has blown), glow brightly (belt cracked), blink with ~1/500 the speed of the motor (diode has blown) or blink irregularily (belt slipping.)

Comment: Oh, and don't forget to put a contact of your keylock in series with the bulb so the alternator doesn't drain your battery when you don't want to run the motor.

Answer (score 0):

The D+ (three diode) supplies a voltage to energize the field coil (rotor) that supplies DF. If the voltage reaches 13.7 to 14.3 V (no more than 15 V), the transistor, MOSFET, or IGBT will turn off the power at DF.

When the voltage drops to the specific voltage (depending on the sensing Zener diode that turns the transistor, MOSFET, or IGBT on and off) it will turn on again.

Since it will turn on and off independently it will not disturb the current at the battery during charging which would make noise. That is why it is directly connected at the AVR. D+ is also connected to the charging lamp; during operation it will give a positive output and turn off the charging lamp.